# DataTables - this.api for multiple tables in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have followed [this example](http://live.datatables.net/rilovoho/1/edit) to add dropdown filtering on my DataTables. It works fine when there is only 1 table on a page but I have a scenario where I have 2 tables.

As per the DataTables documentation ([link 1](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table()), [link 2](https://datatables.net/reference/api/tables())), the API get access to all the DataTables instance at the same time.

So, I tried to target each table with something like

> this.api().tables([0]).columns([3, 4]).every( function () {

but the filtering drop downs are appearing in the 1st table only.

```
 $('#table1').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"dtWrapper"<f>lrti<"paginate0rem"p>>',
        drawCallback: function(){
            if (feather) {
                feather.replace({
                    width: 14,
                    height: 14
                });
            }
        },
        orderCellsTop: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().tables([0]).columns([3, 4]).every( function () {
                let column = this,
                    select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + this.index()  + ')'))
                        .on('change', function () {
                            let val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>')
                });
            });
        }
    });

    $('#table2').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"dtWrapper"<f>lrti<"paginate0rem"p>>',
        drawCallback: function(){
            if (feather) {
                feather.replace({
                    width: 14,
                    height: 14
                });
            }
        },
        orderCellsTop: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().tables([1]).columns([2, 3]).every( function () {
                let column = this,
                    select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + this.index()  + ')'))
                        .on('change', function () {
                            let val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>')
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor there were some typos in my code. I fixed It. Can you check out the post again please.

Comment: If you have a working demo then I will happily have a look for you.

Comment: @LeeTaylor here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deauv7sh/

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calls to `this.api().tables([0])` didn't seem to work for the second table, as you will have noticed. I suspect this would work if you used two tables in one selector to create your DataTables (e.g. `$("#table1, #table2").DataTables()`). As such, changing this to use the actual selector of the required table e.g. `$("#table1").DataTable().columns([2])` works much better. There may be a way of getting the "contextual" datatable without using the selector. But this should get you going in the right direction.
2. Your `.appendTo()` call was attempting to select all the `thead tr:eq(1)` in your html. So, if you would have got the first step working, this broken appending would have caused problems.

See the demo with these fixes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table1').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"dtWrapper"<f>lrti<"paginate0rem"p>>',
    orderCellsTop: true,
    initComplete: function() {
      var $table = $("#table1");
      $table.DataTable().columns([2]).every(function() {
        let column = this;
        let select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($table.find('thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + this.index() + ')'))
          .on('change', function() {
            let val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    }
  });

  $('#table2').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"dtWrapper"<f>lrti<"paginate0rem"p>>',
    orderCellsTop: true,
    initComplete: function() {
      var $table = $("#table2");

      $table.DataTable().columns([3]).every(function() {
        let column = this;
        let select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($table.find('thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + this.index() + ')'))
          .on('change', function() {
            let val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<body>
  <div>
    <table id="table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>col 1</td>
          <td>col 2</td>
          <td>col 3</td>
          <td>col 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>col 1</td>
          <td>col 2</td>
          <td>col 3</td>
          <td>col 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="table2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>col 1</td>
          <td>col 2</td>
          <td>col 3</td>
          <td>col 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>col 1</td>
          <td>col 2</td>
          <td>col 3</td>
          <td>col 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```